# vscode: create files with local user as owner when connected to remote container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, dockerfile, vscode-remote

I have a dockerized Django application (`Dockerfile` + `docker-compose.yml` in project root).

I have three services:

1. `nginx`
2. `postgres`
3. `django`

I'm trying to use VScode with the Remote-Containers extension, so what I have right now is a `.devcontainer` directory with two files (this was setup automatically):

1. `devcontainer.json`
2. `docker-compose.yml` (yes, another one apart from the one in the project root)

Here's the issue. I open vscode and I choose `Reopen in Container` option. This brings up all the services just fine. The thing is any time I create a file via vscode or using bash inside the container, it gets created with owner `root`. This is because `root` is the default user for the `django` container.

I looked into possible solutions, but I can only find ones involving adding a non-root user in the `Dockerfile`. I am not the maintainer of the `Dockerfile` so, I don't wanna do this. I am not the maintainer of the `docker-compose.yml` either but I figure this is ok to change. I can always just stash my changes and pop them if there's any change to this particular file.

Having that in mind, I edited the `docker-compose.yml` and added the line `user: "${HOST_USER}"` to my django container (`HOST_USER` is an env variable that evaluates to `1000:1000`) but then I get permission errors:

[image]

All I want is to be able to use django container as my dev environment without having to worry about file permissions. Is maybe the `Dockerfile` inside the `.devcontainer` directory the way to go? If so, what would I have to add?

`.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Existing Docker Compose (Extend)",

    "dockerComposeFile": [
        "../docker-compose.yml",
        "docker-compose.yml"
    ],

    "service": "django",

    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",

    "settings": {},

    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python"
    ]
}
```

`.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  django:
    # Uncomment if you want to override the service's Dockerfile to one in the .devcontainer 
    # folder. Note that the path of the Dockerfile and context is relative to the *primary* 
    # docker-compose.yml file (the first in the devcontainer.json "dockerComposeFile"
    # array). The sample below assumes your primary file is in the root of your project.
    #
    # build:
    #   context: .
    #   dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile  (MAYBE THIS SOLVES THE ISSUE?)
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace
    command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
```